# Get values from nested object with dynamic ids - javascript

Tags: javascript, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I'm recieving a payload from SlackAPI (block elements) and I can't get my head around oh how do I get data from it as ids and order always change.
I want to get protection_fee.value, legal_fee.value and repayment_date.selected_date

```
"state": {
"values": {
  "CjV": {
    "protection_fee": {
      "type": "plain_text_input",
      "value": "111"
    }
  },
  "36tAM": {
    "legal_fee": {
      "type": "plain_text_input",
      "value": "111"
    }
  },
  "oH8": {
    "repayment_date": {
      "type": "datepicker",
      "selected_date": "1990-04-18"
    }
  }
}
```

},

I tried Object.keys but obviously I failed as order changes.

current code:

```
      const payload = JSON.parse(body);
      const state = payload.state.values;
      const first = Object.keys(state)[0];
      const second = Object.keys(state)[1];
      const repaymentDate = state[first].protection_fee.value;
      const protectionFee = state[second].legal_fee.value;
```

Comment: Does the order really matter with `Object.keys`? You can just iterate with `forEach`, ignore the keys and check for desired field name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a function like `findProperty()` that will find the relevant object in the payload.

We'd call [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) on the `payload.state.values` object and then using [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on the entry key/value pairs to find an object with the desired property.

Once we have the property we can return it.

```js
let payload = { "state": { "values": { "CjV": { "protection_fee": { "type": "plain_text_input", "value": "111" } }, "36tAM": { "legal_fee": { "type": "plain_text_input", "value": "111" } }, "oH8": { "repayment_date": { "type": "datepicker", "selected_date": "1990-04-18" } } } } }

function findProperty(obj, key) {
    const [, value] = Object.entries(obj).find(([k,v]) => v[key]);
    return value[key];
}

console.log('legal_fee:', findProperty(payload.state.values, 'legal_fee').value)
console.log('protection_fee:', findProperty(payload.state.values, 'protection_fee').value)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Absolutely amazing, thank you Terry . Would you mind expalining  const [, value] = Object.entries(obj).find(([k,v]) => v[key]); ?  or maybe pointing to some guide/docs as I tried using Array.find() but well... :) Thanks again

Comment: Hi @Andrey, that's a destructuring assignment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment. The Array.find() call will return an array like [key, value]. In this case we only need value, so we'll omit key in the assignment. You could also use: const [key, value] = Object.entries(obj).find(([k,v]) => v[key]); Hope this helps!